# Matlab: sorting strings on size in a struct field

Tags: string, matlab, sorting, struct, dir

This problem is bugging me and the solution is probably obvious but i cant find it.

I have a bunch of data files which i want to load:

```
ex_file-1.txt, ex_file-2.txt, ..., ex_file-10.txt
```

To get their filenames i use:

```
files = dir('ex_file-*.txt');
```

This returns a struct with fields name, type, etc. The field name returns:

```
ex_file-1.txt, ex_file-10.txt, ex_file-2.txt, ..., ex_file-9.txt
```

I would like to sort this such that `ex_file-10.txt` is the last file rather than the second.

I have attempted to concatenate, convert to cells and sort but none seem to give what i need. I know that the most obvious solution would be to rename all file names so all strings have the same length but i'd prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a alternative which does not require any details about the file name. Primary sorting rule shortest first, secondary lexicographic:

```
%secondary sorting
list=sort(list);
%primary sorting by length
[a,b]=sort(cellfun(@numel,list)):
list=list(b);
```

Comment: The first sort does not work, but the second one does. I choose this as the accepted answer because it is the shortest out of the answers!

Comment: @nlooije: The first sort just verifies that the input is lexicographic sorted. The output of dir is already sorted this way, so it might be unnecessary. Try inputs like `{'ex_file-2.txt','ex_file-1.txt'}`, both sorts are required to deal with unsorted input.

Answer (score 2):

This could be one approach -

```
%// Input cell array of filenames
names = {'ex_file-1.txt', 'ex_file-10.txt', 'ex_file-2.txt', 'ex_file-3.txt', ...
    'ex_file-4.txt',  'ex_file-5.txt'}

%// Reomove the starting common "ex_file" string
stripped_names = strrep(names,'ex_file-','')

%// Remove the ending extension part
stripped_names = strrep(stripped_names,'.txt','')

%// Convert to doubles and then get the sorted indices
[~,idx] = sort(str2double(stripped_names))

%// Use sorted indices to rearrange names array, for the final output
names_out = names(idx)
```

Code run -

```
>> names
names = 
    'ex_file-1.txt'    'ex_file-10.txt'    'ex_file-2.txt'    'ex_file-3.txt'    'ex_file-4.txt'    'ex_file-5.txt'
>> names_out
names_out = 
    'ex_file-1.txt'    'ex_file-2.txt'    'ex_file-3.txt'    'ex_file-4.txt'    'ex_file-5.txt'    'ex_file-10.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using regular expressions. The numeric part of file name is detected as a subsequence of numeric characters right before the `.txt` part.

```
files = dir('ex_file-*.txt'); %// get file struct array
names = {files.name}; %// get file names. Cell array of strings
numbers = regexp(names, '\d+(?=\.txt)', 'match'); %// strings with numeric part of name
numbers = str2double([numbers{:}]); %// convert from strings to numbers
[~, ind] = sort(numbers); %// sort those numbers
names_sorted = names(ind); %// apply that order to file names
```